# What is the Fetch API equivalent of XMLHttpRequest.send(file)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, dom, fetch-api

I am trying to refactor a client to an old backend from XMLHttpRequest to use the Fetch API instead, and I am having a hard time figuring out what the Fetch API equivalent of xhr.send(file) is in the code below.

```
input.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var file = event.target.files[0];
  var url = 'https://somedomain.com/someendpoint';
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
  xhr.send(file);
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`fetch` can take a [second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch#Syntax), `init`, which specifies advanced options of the request.  In particular, you can specify the `method` and the `body` options:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: new Headers({
    "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
  }),
  body: file,
})
```

You can also pass the same options to the `Request` [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request#Syntax).

`body` must a Blob, BufferSource, FormData, URLSearchParams, or USVString object.  Fortunately, File objects are just a special kind of Blobs, and can be used [everywhere where Blobs are accepted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File).

Comment: You win! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done like this:

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]')

var data = new FormData()
data.append('file', input.files[0])

fetch('/avatars', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data
})
```

https://github.com/github/fetch

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: This is the way I found on many internet sites, but it is not equivalent. I have tried this and it does not work. However, the solution by Stas Malolepszy does.